# in Joomla 3.8 default search tools do not respond in my own component and cannot set and get state of the filters

Tags: component, development, search, joomla3.8, filter

I try to get some help from you to spot what I am doing wrong (what I am missing) on applying search tools and filters in the admin of Joomla 3.8 in my own component.

I am pulling my hairs out since I cannot figure out why the search and the filters are not working for me, in other words, the search field is not responding, the search tools/hidden filter does not open.

Only if I click on the clear filters/search button then it refreshes the page with cleared filters. Sorting of fields/columns are working. My only guess is that it is a Jquery/Javascript problem but I do not really know what. Please help me if you can. Thanks in advance!

We are in the view/model called 'products', so my filters' xml:

**../models/forms/filter_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="filter">
        <field
            name="search"
            type="text"
            label="COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_SEARCH_IN_TITLE"
            hint="JSEARCH_FILTER"
            class="JSEARCH_FILTER"
        />
      <field
            name="availability"
            type="list"
            label="JOPTION_SELECT_AVAILABLE"
            description="JOPTION_SELECT_AVAILABLE_DESC"
            default=""
            onchange="this.form.submit();"
    >
        <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_VALUE</option>
        <option value="1">Available</option>
        <option value="0">Unavailable</option>
      </field>
  </fields>
  <fields name="list">
      <field
            name="fullordering"
            type="list"
            label="COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_LIST_FULL_ORDERING"
            description="COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_LIST_FULL_ORDERING_DESC"
            onchange="this.form.submit();"
            default="item_id ASC"
      >
        <option value="">JGLOBAL_SORT_BY</option>
        <option value="a.item_id ASC">COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_ID_ASC</option>
        <option value="a.item_id DESC">COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_ID_DESC</option>
        <option value="a.product_name ASC">COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_PNAME_ASC</option>
        <option value="a.product_name DESC">COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_PNAME_DESC</option>
        <option value="a.availability ASC">COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_AVAILABILITY_ASC</option>
        <option value="a.availability DESC">COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_AVAILABILITY_DESC</option>
    </field>
    <field
            name="limit"
            type="limitbox"
            class="input-mini"
            default="20"
            label="COM_CONTENT_LIST_LIMIT"
            description="COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_LIST_LIMIT_DESC"
            onchange="this.form.submit();"
    />
  </fields>
</form>
```

**../models/products.php**

```
class MoreproductinfoModelProducts extends ListModel
{

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param   array  $config  An optional associative array of configuration settings.
 *
 * @see     JController
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
    {
        $config['filter_fields'] = array(
            'item_id', 'a.item_id',
            'product_name', 'a.product_name',
            'product_id', 'a.product_id',
            'variant_id', 'a.variant_id',                
            'product_sku', 'a.product_sku',
            'avalability', 'a.availability',                
        );
    }

    JLoader::register('MoreproductinfoHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/helpers/moreproductinfo.php');

    parent::__construct($config);
}

protected function populateState($ordering = 'a.item_id', $direction = 'asc')
{
    // Initialise variables.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();        

    $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
    $this->setState('filter.search', $search);        

    $availability = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.availability', 'filter_availability', '', 'string');
    $this->setState('filter.availability', $availability);


    // List state information.
    parent::populateState($ordering, $direction);

}

function getListQuery()
{
    // Initialize variables.
    $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $user  = JFactory::getUser();

    // Select the required fields from the table.
    $query->select(
        $this->getState(
            'list.select',
            'a.item_id' .
            ', a.product_name, a.product_id, a.variant_id, a.variation_option_name, a.variation_image_param_url' .
            ', a.product_sku, a.availability, a.arrival_date, a.params, a.last_check')
    );
    $query->from('#__moreproductinfo_items AS a');        

    // Filter: product_name / search
    $search = $this->getState('filter.search');        

    if (!empty($search))
    {
        $search = $db->quote('%' . str_replace(' ', '%', $db->escape(trim($search), true) . '%'));
        // $like = $db->quote('%' . $search . '%');
        $query->where('a.product_name LIKE ' . $search);
    }

    // Filter by availability state
    $available = $this->getState('filter.availability');
    // $available = 0; -- debug - filter works if I define value here

    if (is_numeric($available))
    {
        $query->where('availability = ' . (int) $available);
    }
    elseif ($available === '')
    {
        $query->where('(availability IN (0, 1))');
    }

    // Add the list ordering clause.
    $orderCol   = $this->getState('list.ordering', 'item_id');
    $orderDirn  = $this->getState('list.direction', 'asc');

    $query->order($db->escape($orderCol) . ' ' . $db->escape($orderDirn));

    return $query;

}

function getItems()
{
    $items = parent::getItems();

    foreach ($items as $item) {

        $item->url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_moreproductinfo&task=product.edit&item_id=' . $item->item_id);

        $item->img_url = JRoute::_(URI::root() . $item->variation_image_param_url);

    }

    return $items;

}
```

Then the view.html file:
**../views/products/view.html.php**

```
public function display($tpl = null)
    {

        // to call nessecary JS
        HTMLHelper::_('behavior.framework');  

        // define state and pagination - from model
        // define items from model
        $this->items = $this->get('Items');
        $this->state        = $this->get('State');
        $this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');            
        $this->filterForm       = $this->get('FilterForm');
        $this->activeFilters    = $this->get('ActiveFilters');

        // Show the toolbar - set the toolbar
        $this->toolbar();

        // adding toolbars
        $this->addToolbar();

        // Show the sidebar
        $this->helper = new MoreproductinfoHelper;            
        $this->helper->addSubmenu('products');
        $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();

        // Display it all
        return parent::display($tpl);           

    }
```

and finally the tmpl default layout:
**../views/products/tmpl/default.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
use \Joomla\CMS\language\Text;
use \Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use \Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper;

HTMLHelper::_('behavior.core');
HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.tooltip');
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.multiselect');
HTMLHelper::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');

$app       = JFactory::getApplication();
$user      = JFactory::getUser();

$listOrder     = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering'));
$listDirn      = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.direction'));

?>

<div id="j-sidebar-container" class="span2">
    <?php echo $this->sidebar; ?>
</div>
<div id="j-main-container" class="span10">

    <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert"><p><?php echo Text::_('COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_PRODUCTS_LAST_REFRESHED') . $this->date; ?></p></div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10">
        <?php echo JText::_('COM_MOREPRODUCTINFO_PRODUCTS_FILTER'); ?>
        <?php
        echo LayoutHelper::render(
            'joomla.searchtools.default',
            array('view' => $this)
        );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_moreproductinfo&view=products'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>...

... // a lot of html and php which shows the items....

    </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
        <?php echo HTMLHelper::_('form.token'); ?>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spotted out my small but really basic, stupid mistake in my own code (above). So, of course I could not really expect that someone will come and stares at a lot of code and spot any mistake in a big amount of code right away. It took for me like 3 days to spot this tiny, but very annoying problem. The above code is OK, except one thing.

**It's very simple:** I placed the **'joomla.searchtools.default'** outside of the html **Form** in my **tmpl/default.php** file and that is why - of course - it was not responding, and of course I was unable to control, set and get the filters (from requests) due to this simple and very basic mistake I made in the layout.

And earlier I thought that it was a javascript problem. This is just another example of not seeing the wood for the trees... :)